Movie\show with morse code scene on a submarine?
I am pretty sure that this is a movie, not a TV show, but I don't want to rule it out.  I really don't remember much, but I vividly remember a scene where there is a prisoner/someone who is captured (I think he may have spoke a different language) on a submarine and bangs on some pipes or something on the sub in morse code, trying to communicate with his people/country/whatever.  I want to say he was morsing SOS, but am not positive.  Someone on the crew eventually picks up on what he is doing and they go stop him (can't remember if they knock him out or kill him or anything like that).  
I am also fairly certain there is another scene in the movie where they are dropping depth charges on the submarine to try and locate it. I think the sub goes very very low but eventually loses power and needs to come up otherwise it may sink.
I can't quite remember a year this movie could be from, but I'm 99% sure it wasn't 2000s.

I vaguely recall (it was a pretty forgettable movie) Steel Sharks having a scene like that.

This sounds like U-571 (2000) with Matthew McConaughey, Bill Paxton and Harvey Keitel.

In the midst of World War II, the battle below the seas rages. The Nazi's have the upper edge as the Allies are unable to crack their war codes. That is, until a wrecked U-boat sends out an SOS signal, and the Allies realise this is their chance to seize the 'enigma coding machine'. But masquerading as Nazi's and taking over the U-boat is the smallest of their problems. The action really begins when they get stranded on the U-boat.

And at some point:

McConaughey then orders the sub to go down to 150 meters which is almost unheard of, especially for a sub in such poor condition. Keitel, acting a little like Scotty from Star Trek, tells him that the ship can't handle it and will be crushed. The destroyer drops depth charges and nearly destroys the sub. For some reason, the Germans don't stop and keep dropping the charges. Turns out that the German Captain on board is tapping their position off the side of the sub in morse code to the German destroyer. 

You can see the morse code scene here, and here's the trailer:




While it sounds similar, I don't think this is it.  Unless you can confirm the morse code scene.. that's what I remember most.

Yes, that scene is definitely in this movie.

@Snowman It was "I am U-571. Destroy me."
